# Objective C to SwiftUI Hide Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swiftui

I have an Objective C app that navigates to a SwiftUI layout.
When it does this there is a blank area at the top of the screen that I believe is a navigation bar. The original Objective C layout does not have a navigation bar.

Where in the code below do I remove the navigation bar?

This is how I open the SwiftUI layout from Objective C:

```
@property SwuiftUIInterface *goldieInterface;
@property UIViewController *swiftViewController;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 self.goldieInterface = [[SwuiftUIInterface alloc] init];
 self.swiftViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    
 self.swiftViewController = [self.goldieInterface makeSwiftUI:macAddresses];

 [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self.swiftViewController] animated:YES];
}
```

This is the SwiftUIInterface function makeSwiftUI:

```
@objc class SwuiftUIInterface: NSObject {

@objc func makeSwiftUI(_ macAddr:String) ->
UIViewController{

    var details = SwiftUIView(runTimer: true)
    
    return UIHostingController(rootView: details)
}}
```

This is my SwiftUIView:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications
struct SwiftUIView: View {
var body: some View {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the solution was in getting access to the UIHostingController

To get access I added this to the SwiftUIInterface file:

```
class YourHostingController <Content>: UIHostingController<AnyView> where Content : View {

  public init(shouldShowNavigationBar: Bool, rootView: Content) {
      super.init(rootView: AnyView(rootView.navigationBarHidden(!shouldShowNavigationBar)))
  }

  @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

I then changed the SwiftUIInterface class like so

```
@objc class SwuiftUIInterface: NSObject {

    @objc func makeSwiftUI(_ macAddr:String) ->
    UIViewController{
        print("swift interface Make set ui view controller")            
        let details = SwiftUIView(runTimer: true)
        let sleepFreq: YourHostingController = YourHostingController(shouldShowNavigationBar: false, rootView: details)
        
        return sleepFreq

    }
}
```